Load all the localized Messages in Fusinauth Theme
I am working on customization error messages on Fusionauth Theme. Need to load localized messages to javascript so that I can display later as freemarker is running server side only.
${theme.messages}
${theme.getMessages()}
[#list theme.messages as m][/#list]

